# Rails mechanize data scraping correct data/cleaning it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm having trouble scraping the exact piece of data I want from the UCAS website.

Currently I'm pulling the course title using the below code:

```
  course_page.search('ol.resultscontainer li').each do |course|
  @course_name = course.search('.courseTitle').text
```

Which provides me with, for example:

```
 Mathematics (PGDE - Graduates only)
```

And with the below I'm pulling the course title with the UCAS code in brackets:

```
 course_page.search('ol.resultscontainer li').each do |course|
            @ucas_numb = clean_text(course.search('h4').text)
```

Which provides me with:

```
Mathematics (PGDE - Graduates only)(G1X1)
```

All I want to pull in the last example is the UCAS code (G1X1 in the example above). Can anybody help me with a method of either cleaning this or how to select just the UCAS code to be scraped?

Below is the code from the UCAS website I'm scraping which deals with the data I want to scrape:

```
    <h4><a href="/course/summary/452492/mathematics-pgde-graduates-only?Count…&page=6&providerids=41&Feather=7&MaxResults=1000&ret=results">

        <span class="courseTitle"></span>
    (G1X1)
</a> <h4>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who would like to know, I sloved this by removing the span class using the code below:

```
            # Removes excess html which was interferring with text
            course.search(
                '.coursenamearea a span,').remove
```